# XPath problem with multiple OR expressions like (a|b|c)

Tags: xpath

I have simplified html:

```
    <html>
        <main>
            <span>one</span>
        </main>

        <not_important>
            <div>skip_me</div>
        </not_important>

        <support>
            <div>two</div>
        </support>
    </html>
```

I want to find only `one` and `two`, using conditions that the parent tag is `main` or `support`, and there is `span` or `div`after it.

I wonder why that code does not work:

```
import lxml.html as HTML_PARSER
html = """
    <html>
        <main>
            <span>one</span>
        </main>

        <not_important>
            <div>skip_me</div>
        </not_important>

        <support>
            <div>two</div>
        </support>
    </html>
"""
parent = '//main | //support'
child = '/span | /div'
doc = HTML_PARSER.fromstring(html)
print doc

xpath = '(%s)(%s)' % (parent, child)
print xpath
parsed = doc.xpath(xpath)
print parsed
```

I get an error `Invalid expression`. Why?

This `(//main | //support)` and this `(/span | /div)` xpaths are both correct.
Simple combo like `(//main | //support)/span` is also correct.
But why more complicated combination `(//main | //support)(/span | /div)` is not correct? How to resolve it?

In my real case `//main`, `//support`, `/span` and `/div` are really complicated xpaths, I want some general solution like `(xpath1 | xpath2)(xpath3 | xpath4)`

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding:  In XPath, `|` is a set union operator, *not* logical OR.  Furthermore, any given expressions being syntactically valid in a language doesn't mean an arbitrary combination of those expressions is syntactically valid.  Grammar rules for the combination still have to be followed.

Comment: If you want all children of only `main` or `support` elements, then use `//*[self::main or self::support]/*`.  (You can of course further filter those children with an additional predicate if needed.)  Everyone offering answers that indulge your use of `|` as logical OR is being less clear than they should be.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is not valid for XPath version 1 (the one that lxml use)

Try

```
xpath = '//div[parent::support]|//span[parent::main]'
```

or

```
parent = ['main', 'support']
child = ['span', 'div']
xpath = '//*[self::{0[0]} or self::{0[1]}]/*[self::{1[0]} or self::{1[1]}]'.format(parent, child)
```

Answer (score 0):

this will find it, however I'm not 100% sure if it's what you want:

```
//*[name() = 'main' or name() = 'support']/*[name() = 'span' or name() = 'div']/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `self::` axis:

```
(//main | //support)[*[self::div or self::span]]
```